# XML Validation error -Root element must match doctype

Tags: xml

Im trying to validate my XML file with an external DTD. But I get this error everytime.

```
Document root element "A", must match DOCTYPE root "test".
```

i cant figure this out.

The idea of my xml file is that its need to be as short as possible .
I thinkt its all good but like i said, i wont validate. Does someone have an idea ?

This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE test SYSTEM "test.dtd">

<A>
<B>
<F>name</F>
</B>
<D>lastname</D>
<F>name</F>
</A>
```

And my DTD

```
<!ELEMENT A (B, (C|D), E?, (F, G?)+)>
<!ELEMENT B (F|G)+>
<!ELEMENT D (#PCDATA|C)*>
<!ELEMENT F (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT G (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT C (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT E (#PCDATA)>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Doctype claims the root element is `<test>` but you have used `<A>`

```
<!DOCTYPE test
          ^^^^
```

Either change the Doctype so it claims the root is `<A>` or change the XML and DTD to use `<test>`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<!DOCTYPE test SYSTEM "test.dtd">
```

Declares that the root ELEMENT of the DTD-conformant document is called `test`. You want:

```
<!DOCTYPE A SYSTEM "test.dtd">
```