# Error parsing XML using certain schema with Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema

I'm trying to parse a file (I am sure the file is syntactically correct, it was generated) using [this schema](http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_schema_1_4). The file begins as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
    ...
```

This is my code to load it:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

dbFactory.setValidating(true);

SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
URL schemaURL = new URL("http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_schema_1_4");
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(schemaURL);
dbFactory.setSchema(schema);

DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
docBuilder.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        System.err.print("Warning: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        System.err.print("FATAL ERROR: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        System.err.print("Error: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file); //Line throwing error
```

Parsing it as such throws the following error:

```
Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/ukraine/Desktop/Code/Java/Eclipse/3D%20Previewer/models/cube.dae; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 79; Element type "COLLADA" must be declared.
    at ...
Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/.../cube.dae; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 79; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'COLLADA'.
    at ...
Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/.../cube.dae; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 9; Element type "asset" must be declared.
    at ...
```

Even though I'm fairly sure that this syntax is correct, I tried adding `<!DOCTYPE COLLADA>` as per the recommendation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402292/xml-validation-error-root-element-must-match-doctype), which threw an exception saying:

```
FATAL ERROR: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/.../cube.dae; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

**EDIT:** These are the errors I've gotten from suggestions thus far:

When setting up `DocumentBuilder` as namespace aware:

```
Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/.../cube.dae; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 9; Document is invalid: no grammar found.
```

When adding an `xsi:schemaLocation`:

```
Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/.../cube.dae; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 26; Document root element "COLLADA", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
```

Comment: There is junk at the front of your file before the XML prolog. Perhaps there is a BOM and you are using a really old version of Java?

Comment: @bmargulies I'm on java 7. And I'm not exactly sure to which file you are referring to and what the junk is.

Comment: @bmargulies is addressing the error that you received when you added the `<!DOCTYPE COLLADA>` line.  You probably added it before the XML declaration, and nothing can appear before the XML declaration.  Regardless, you don't need a DOCTYPE line.  The real problem (indicated by `Element type "COLLADA" must be declared.
    at ...`) is that your XSD is not being found.  You can use `xsi:schemaLocation` as I show in my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29313467/290085) to hint to the XML parser where to find the XSD.

Comment: @kjhughes It didn't work for me. I got this error: `Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/.../cube.dae; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 26; Document root element "COLLADA", must match DOCTYPE root "null".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the DocumentBuilder to be namespace-aware. (Do you really need to use DOM anyway?)

And you shouldn't declare it with setValidating() unless you want DTD validation (as distinct from schema validation).

Comment: `Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/.../cube.dae; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 9; Document is invalid: no grammar found.`

Comment: Added to the answer. You don't want to call setValidating(true) unless there is a DTD.

Answer (score 0):

**The XSD is not being found.**  One way to make the association between your XML instance and its governing XSD is via `xsi:schemaLocation`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema
                             https://www.khronos.org/files/collada_schema_1_4"
         version="1.4.1">
...
```

Comment: `Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/.../cube.dae; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 26; Document root element "COLLADA", must match DOCTYPE root "null".`

Comment: I removed it before I tested if.